# Remove embedded html tags with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

My input xml has embedded html tags in Emp_Name and Country Elements and I need to strip off only html tags to get the below desired output.

Could you please assist how this can be achieved in XSLT.

Input XML:

```
 <root>
 <Record>
<Emp_ID>288237</Emp_ID>
<Emp_Name> <br>John</br></Emp_Name>
<Country><p>US</p></Country>
<Manager>Wills</Manager>
<Join_Date>5/12/2014</Join_Date>
<Experience>9 years</Experience>
<Project>abc</Project>
<Skill>java</Skill>
</Record>
```

Desired Output:

```
 <root>
 <Record>
<Emp_ID>288237</Emp_ID>
<Emp_Name>John</Emp_Name>
<Country>US</Country>
<Manager>Wills</Manager>
<Join_Date>5/12/2014</Join_Date>
<Experience>9 years</Experience>
<Project>abc</Project>
<Skill>java</Skill>
</Record>
```

Comment: I have rolled your question back to its original form, because the new question is *fundamentally* different. Please post a new question.

Answer (score 3):

If you know in advance which HTML tags are used, you can do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="br|p">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### EDIT:

> is it possible to write xslt for those two fields explicitly as I may
>   receive any html tags(not `<br>` and `<p>` alone) for that elements.

Then how about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Emp_Name|Country">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But, is it possible to write xslt for those two elements explicitly as I may receive any html tags(not <br> and <p> alone) for that elements.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: It is working fine. But when I try to call this xslt in our tool the input XML tags are being sensed as &lt; and &gt; Is it possible to write an XSLT to strip html tags based on &lt; and &gt; ?

I have modified the input XML in the question.

Comment: @Vivek Your new question cannot be answered by modifying the above answer. It requires a radically different approach. Please start a new question.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks for the reply. I have started a new question in the below thread.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738487/strip-html-tags-in-xml-having-lt-and-gt-using-xslt